# Making the Text in a Text Cell change color when the Rows Checkbox has been checked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a NSOutlineView and I want to make the text for a row change color when the rows check box has been checked.

The Outline View looks like:

```
 _     _________________
|_|   |____TEXT CELL____|
 _     _________________
|_|   |____TEXT CELL____|
 _     _________________
|_|   |____TEXT CELL____|
(CHECKBOX)
```

How would I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can target 10.6, implement `tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:` in your table view's delegate to set the cell's text color based on the value of whatever property that backs the checkbox.

Comment: Hmm. Isn't there an easier way, I seem to remember something about using a Binding to do this, is that possible?

Comment: It's possible to bind the table column's text color, yes. But your question sounds more like you're using text color to display the same property as the checkbox in a different way, which means that the text-color binding—which would require a text-color property of the model object—isn't appropriate.

Comment: So would the code look a bit like this, http://fwdr.org/z2ek. But what would I put where I said 'What would I put here' to check if the check box on the row is checked?

Comment: First, you need to make sure you're looking at the correct column, which you can do by comparing the column's identifier (you *did* assign the columns identifiers in IB, right?). This is better than a `respondsToSelector:` check, since you may have multiple text cells.

Comment: Next, get the model object at the specified row, then get its value for the property that the checkbox column shows. Set the cell's `textColor` based on that value.

Comment: Is this better. http://pastebin.com/d225a6b33. Does the Code at the top get the model object at the specified row? However, I still don't understand how I would 'get its value for the property that the checkbox column shows'.

Comment: Well, you wrote it. You tell me what it does.

Comment: Item equals the item at row index.

Comment: It is the Row that is Selected or at the row index.

Comment: I don't see a condition in that statement. That means it only does one thing, not one thing or a different thing. So: Which one is it?

Comment: Ok. It's the row at the row index.